Unable to substitute cloudformation correctly with Fn Sub or !Sub
I have tried few approaches to substitute the following IAM role for EBS CSI driver service account. however i kept getting formatting error or invalidity to substitute
what i have tried -
  EBSCSIDriverRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Federated: !Ref EKSClusterOIDCProvider
            Action: sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
            Condition:
              StringEquals: !Sub
                - '${OIDCProvider}:sub': 'system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa'
                - OIDCProvider: !GetAtt EKSCluster.OpenIdConnectIssuerUrl
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy

Or with Fn:sub
EBSCSIDriverRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Federated: !Ref EKSClusterOIDCProvider
          Action: sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              Fn::Sub: 
                - "${OIDCProvider}:sub"
                - OIDCProvider: !Ref EKSClusterOIDCProvider
              : "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"
    ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy

All giving me Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string
I double checked against the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html
also tried with String only like:
 Condition:
              StringEquals: !Sub
                - "${OIDCProvider}:sub: system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"
                - OIDCProvider: !GetAtt EKSCluster.OpenIdConnectIssuerUrl

although that doesn't throw formatting error anymore but when i deploy update cloudformation throws error
Resource handler returned message: "Syntax error at position (1,210) (Service: Iam, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 397c0cf6-8576-4e8c-ada3-682b23b782e0)" (RequestToken: 582869e7-cba5-4c3c-7418-fcf5845c4eb1, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
and tried few other combinations of patterns but to no avail. anybody can shed some lights on this?
thanks in advance!

i got a workaround due to the special situation to do with the StringEquals attribute in the Condition expects a dynamic value such as:
oidc.eks.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/id/$some_id:sub
This is unusual and specific to this case i realised.
what's working:
EBSCSIDriverRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: !Sub
        - |
          {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                  "Federated": "${OIDCProviderArn}"
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "Condition": {
                  "StringEquals": {
                    "${OIDCProviderUrl}:sub": "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        - OIDCProviderArn: !Ref EKSClusterOIDCProvider
          OIDCProviderUrl: 
            !Select 
              - 1
              - !Split ["https://", !GetAtt EKSCluster.OpenIdConnectIssuerUrl]
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy

